# Is it possible to post an array with $http.post?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http-post, angularjs-service

I'm trying to save an json array to service in back-end via $http.post but I always get `400 Bad Request`. I have googled all around and there's not a clear answer to be found.

My questions are follows:
1. Is it possible to post json array via $http.post?
2. If yes, how it is done?
3. If no, what other alternatives there would be to save json array with such aim?

To make this even more clear, I'm going to add some of my codes below which are necessary.

**At Front-end**

**SavingsService**

```
createBatchSavings: function(savingsBatch){
        return $http.post('/finance/savings/create/batchsavings', savingsBatch).success(function(data){
            return data;
        });
    }
```

Above function gets it's savingsBatch parameter properly. savingsBatch is json array.

**At Back-end**

SavingServiceImpl

```
@Component
@Path("/savings")
@Produces("application/json")
public class SavingsServiceImpl implements SavingsService {

@Autowired
FinanceEntityDao financeDao;

@POST
@Path("/create")
public FinanceEntity createSaving(FinanceEntity financeEntity) {
    financeEntity.setType(FinanceType.SAVING);
    financeEntity.setDateAdded(new Date());
    return financeDao.save(financeEntity);
}

@POST
@Path("/create/batchsavings")
public List<FinanceEntity> createBatchSavings(List<FinanceEntity> savingsBatch) {
    if(savingsBatch.size() > 0){
        return financeDao.massSave(savingsBatch);
    }
    else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Saving batch was null!");
    }
}
}
```

I have also examined the header values. Request headers is having proper values but Response headers content-length is always zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is finally solved. There were two problems in this implementation. First one in front-end and second in back-end.

**Front-end**

First problem was that I tried to post json array straightly to Java service class, which won't work, because it must be converted into proper string json array. Code to send the json array from controller to service is something like this:

```
$scope.createBatchSavings = function(batchSavings){
    return SavingsService.createBatchSavings(batchSavings).success(function(data){
        swal("Saving batch saved!", "Saving batch was saved successfully!", "success");
        $scope.savingsBatch = [];
    });
}
```

Here batchSavings is json array which content-type in header was application/json. This must be stringified and thus above method must be written like below in order to pass proper json array to back-end service:

```
$scope.createBatchSavings = function(batchSavings){
    return SavingsService.createBatchSavings(JSON.stringify(batchSavings)).success(function(data){
        swal("Saving batch saved!", "Saving batch was saved successfully!", "success");
        $scope.savingsBatch = [];
    });
}
```

**Back-end**

Secondly this stringified array must be deserialized in the back-end. Previously the connection between front-end service and back-end service didn't even work because of passing inappropriate json array. So the connection was fixed by converting the json array into proper one.

In order for back-end service to work I had to change the parameter type from `List<FinanceEntity>` into `String`. Also I had to choose deserialization "machine". In my case I chose Gson. Thus below method:

```
@POST
@Path("/create/batchsavings")
public List<FinanceEntity> createBatchSavings(List<FinanceEntity> savingsBatch) {
if(savingsBatch.size() > 0){
    return financeDao.massSave(savingsBatch);
}
else {
    throw new NullPointerException("Saving batch was null!");
}
}
```

becomes:

```
@POST
@Path("/create/batchsavings")
public List<FinanceEntity> createBatchSavings(String savingsBatch) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<FinanceEntity>>(){}.getType();
    List<FinanceEntity> savingsList = gson.fromJson(savingsBatch, collectionType);
    if(savingsList.size() > 0){
        return financeDao.massSave(savingsList);
    }
    else {
        throw new NullPointerException("Saving batch was null!");
    }
}
```

Now this whole thing works.

Just as a notification, if you have any dates you must format them into proper format because otherwise you will encounter `Unparsable date` problem in Java.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but angular doesn't need you to stringify the array, it will do that for you; and spring (I think you're using spring on the back end) can use Jackson to decode from JSON to Java objects for you. So, though I'm glad you've got it working, your code is doing work it doesn't need to, and as your app gets bigger, that will become unwieldy.

Comment: Thanks AndrewE, yes I'm using spring on the back end, but not Jackson. As for Jackson replacement I use Jersey, I had some problems with Jackson's libraries that conflicted with Spring libraries, so it was long process of Spring libraries modification, but at least I learned from it :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes its absolutely possible to post an array data and the code you wrote at client side to post data is correct.

The status code `400` you are getting must be due to problem at your server side code. I see a method **createBatchSavings** in your server side code but your URL at client side is lower case, **batchsavings**.

This is just an hint. You need to add more information about server side code.

Comment: I agree. The front end is ok but I suspect the back end is failing to deserialize the JSON into the list of FinanceEntity objects. To the OP, I suggest you try sending a single object (not in a list), using a dict (say, ``{'batch':batch}``) just to see if the back end handles that ok.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal: I don't think it's because of that because I have a function at the front-end called createSaving and it's almost same kind of code with createBatchSavings except the parameter that is passed to that specific function is object instead of json array.

Comment: @AndrewE: I have tried to printout in the back-end at the beginning of createBatchSavings() method the savingBatch list but it doesn't even get there.

Comment: @Amir: Exactly. The server code that invokes your function is failing to match the incoming data to the type you have registered and returns the 400 because the request is bad. You have a few options. You can try changing the types as I mentioned before as an experiment. You can run your server in a debugger, put a breakpoint in your routine and then see how it is invoked and figure out what is going on, or perhaps find a way to receive any object as parameter (``Object``? Nah probably not...).

Comment: @AndreW: thanks for suggestion. I will go and try to find it with way you suggested.

Comment: @AndrewE: thanks Andrew it was all about deserialization and few fixes at the front-end. :)

Answer (score -1):

questions are follows:

1. Is it possible to post json array via $http.post? **yes**
2. If yes, how it is done?

   $http({ method:'POST', url:'api/data', data:item array})
3. If no, what other alternatives there would be to save json array with such aim?

   It is possible.

Comment: if you closely see my createBatchSavings method, that's exactly what is done, according to your second question answer.